# Concat part of date + integer

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to generate a reservation number which consists of 2 date parts and an integer (year, month, and a derived integer.) Here is what i am trying but `CONCAT()` gives error. I have also tried `CONCAT_WS()` and `CAST()` but none worked. Txs.

```
SELECT date_format(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y%m') as my_date,
    a_res_number.res_number + 1 AS res,
    CONCAT(my_date, res) AS number
FROM a_res_number;

UPDATE a_res_number SET a_res_number.res_number = a_res_number.res_number + 1;
```

Comment: Most likely you have to `CAST` the `date_format` to strings.

Comment: For the future, saying "concat() gives error" is not helpful. If you're getting an error and you want help with it, you have to tell us the error!

Comment: ok txs for your suggestion i will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aliases in the call to `CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y%m'), a_res_number.res_number + 1) AS number
FROM a_res_number;
```

Or, if you need those values as part of the final result:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y%m') AS my_date,
    a_res_number.res_number + 1 AS res,
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y%m'), a_res_number.res_number + 1) AS number
FROM a_res_number;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use format (no need to repeat function calls):

```
SELECT my_date, res, CONCAT(my_date, res) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y%m') AS my_date,
    a_res_number.res_number + 1 AS res
  FROM a_res_number
) as q;
```